# Spark dataframe add result of window function to the regular function like max. Auto increment

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to generate auto incremented values for id field. My approach was to use windows function and max function.

I'm trying to find pure dataframe solution (no rdd).

So after I did `right-outer join` I get this dataframe:

```
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2), (3, None), (5, None)], ['someattr', 'id'])

# notice null values? it's a new records that don't have id just yet.
# The task is to generate them. Preferably with one query.

df2.show()

+--------+----+
|someattr|  id|
+--------+----+
|       1|   2|
|       3|null|
|       5|null|
+--------+----+
```

I need to generate auto incremented values for `id` field. My approach was to use windows function

```
df2.withColumn('id', when(df2.id.isNull(), row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('id')) + max('id')).otherwise(df2.id))
```

When I do this it's raises following exception:

```
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-b3221098e895> in <module>()
     10 
     11 
---> 12 df2.withColumn('hello', when(df2.id.isNull(), row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('id')) + max('id')).otherwise(df2.id)).show()

/Users/ipolynets/workspace/spark-2.0.0/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in withColumn(self, colName, col)
   1371         """
   1372         assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
-> 1373         return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sql_ctx)
   1374 
   1375     @ignore_unicode_prefix

/Users/ipolynets/workspace/spark-2.0.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    931         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    932         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 933             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    934 
    935         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/Users/ipolynets/workspace/spark-2.0.0/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))
     68             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '):
---> 69                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     70             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis'):
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

AnalysisException: u"expression '`someattr`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;"
```

Not sure what this exception complains about to be honest.

Notice how I add `window` function to regular `max()` function?

`row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('id')) + max('id')`

I'm not sure if that's even allowed.

Ohh.. and this is expected output of desired query. As you may already figured.

```
+--------+----+
|someattr|  id|
+--------+----+
|       1|   2|
|       3|   3|
|       5|   4|
+--------+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding column, so in result DataFrame there will be also `someattr` column.

You must include `someattr` in `group by` or use it in some aggregation function.

However, it is simpler to do it in this way:

```
df2.registerTempTable("test")
df3 = sqlContext.sql("""
    select t.someattr, nvl (t.id, row_number(partition by id) over () + maxId.maxId) as id
    from test t
    cross join (select max(id) as maxId from test) as maxId
""")
```

Of course you can translate it to DSL, however SQL seems to be more easier for me for this task